# Nodes return empty with libXML2

Tags: c, linux, libxml2

I've extracted this code (as working) from a project. As I am not knowledgeable about `libXML` or `XML` I can't find out the problem to solve. The `XML` file is here [link](http://www.meteor.gov.tr/FTPDATA/analiz/sonSOA.xml)

I get output:

```
Error: empty set as a result of evaluation xpath expression "/SOA/sehirler[0]/Bolge"
Error: empty set as a result of evaluation xpath expression "/SOA/sehirler[0]/Peryot"
Error: empty set as a result of evaluation xpath expression "/SOA/sehirler[0]/İli"
Error: empty set as a result of evaluation xpath expression "/SOA/sehirler[0]/Durum"
Error: empty set as a result of evaluation xpath expression "/SOA/sehirler[0]/Mak"
Segmentation fault
```

As opposed to just getting

```
İstanbul
```

in the console output.

Can be compiled with this

```
gcc -Wall main.c -o out $(pkg-config --cflags --libs glib-2.0 libxml-2.0)
```

The following is working code to be pasted into the main.c

```
#include <glib-2.0/glib.h>

#include <libxml/tree.h>
#include <libxml/parser.h>
#include <libxml/xpath.h>
#include <libxml/xpathInternals.h>

typedef struct weatherXmlSourceNode {
  char *bolge, *peryot, *ili, *durum;
  int mak;
} weatherSource;
weatherSource *wsrc[6];

xmlDocPtr doc;

char *grabNodeFromFile(xmlDocPtr xml_doc, char* nodeName, int item_index) {
  char xpath[64];
  xmlXPathContextPtr xpathCtx; 
  xmlXPathObjectPtr xpathObj; 
  xmlNodeSetPtr nodeset;

  sprintf(xpath, "/SOA/sehirler[%d]/%s",item_index,nodeName);

  xpathCtx = xmlXPathNewContext(xml_doc);

  if(xpathCtx == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr,"Error: unable to create new XPath context\n");
    return(NULL);
  }

  /* Evaluate xpath expression */
  xpathObj = xmlXPathEvalExpression((xmlChar *)xpath, xpathCtx);
  xmlXPathFreeContext(xpathCtx);
  if(xpathObj == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr,"Error: unable to evaluate xpath expression \"%s\"\n", xpath);
    return(NULL);
  }

  /* Check if xmlXPathEvalExpression had returned nonempty nodeset*/
  if (xmlXPathNodeSetIsEmpty(xpathObj->nodesetval)) {
    fprintf(stderr,"Error: empty set as a result of evaluation xpath expression \"%s\"",xpath);
    xmlXPathFreeObject (xpathObj);
    return(NULL);
  }

  nodeset = xpathObj->nodesetval;

  //there should be only one node in nodeset. So we return contents of the first node in nodeset
  return (char *)xmlNodeListGetString(xml_doc, nodeset->nodeTab[0]->xmlChildrenNode,1);
}

void fill_entry_from_rss(weatherSource *wsrc, xmlDocPtr filename, int doc_index) {
  /* Fill respective elements */
  wsrc->bolge = grabNodeFromFile(filename, "Bolge", doc_index);
  wsrc->peryot = grabNodeFromFile(filename, "Peryot", doc_index);
  wsrc->ili = grabNodeFromFile(filename, "İli", doc_index);
  wsrc->durum = grabNodeFromFile(filename, "Durum", doc_index);
  wsrc->mak = grabNodeFromFile(filename, "Mak", doc_index);
}

int fill_entry_from_rss_loop() {
  //int doc_item_index = 1;
  /* Load XML documents */
  doc = xmlParseFile("sonSOA.xml");
  if (doc == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: unable to parse file \"sonSOA.xml\"\n");
    return(0);
  }
  /* Allocate memory for weather struct */
  int num = 6;
  while (num > 0) {
    wsrc[(num - 1)] = g_new0(weatherSource, 1);
    num--;
  }
  /* Fill rss entries from their respective fields */
  fill_entry_from_rss(wsrc[0], doc, 0);
  printf("%s\n", wsrc[0]->ili);
  xmlFreeDoc(doc);
  return 1;
}
int main() {
  fill_entry_from_rss_loop();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Demo input with according output as well as expected output would really help preventing downvotes (and maybe yield a actual problem solution. Also roll up your sleeves and rtfm.

Comment: Added expected vs current output. Also I read the manual. It's also that I had this code working with rss standard, yet when I put it into work on a simple xml file it fails. A simple "heads up you are using the wrong methodology" or "wrong type of path" would be nice @drahnr

Comment: @whotheman add stacktrace or gdb backtrace, preferably with a _handtyped_ (prevent voodoo chars being copied, if any) mini test xml. `grabNodeFromFile` indeed looks fine.

Comment: Thanks drahnr. Turns out xml makers actually put one of the tags not starting with uppercase like the rest, in this example "İli". Still, it is my fault for not recognizing it. But regardless, thanks for helping out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question, 2 mistakes were present in this code. First of all, xml nodes start with 1 rather than 0 when listed. Also "ili" property from the xml was mistyped as "İli" in my code, so that's fixed too. Working code as follows.

```
#include <glib-2.0/glib.h>

#include <libxml/tree.h>
#include <libxml/parser.h>
#include <libxml/xpath.h>
#include <libxml/xpathInternals.h>

typedef struct weatherXmlSourceNode {
  char *bolge, *peryot, *ili, *durum;
  int mak;
} weatherSource;
weatherSource *wsrc[6];

xmlDocPtr doc;

char *grabNodeFromFile(xmlDocPtr xml_doc, char* nodeName, int item_index) {
  char xpath[64];
  xmlXPathContextPtr xpathCtx; 
  xmlXPathObjectPtr xpathObj; 
  xmlNodeSetPtr nodeset;

  sprintf(xpath, "/SOA/sehirler[%d]/%s",item_index,nodeName);

  xpathCtx = xmlXPathNewContext(xml_doc);

  if(xpathCtx == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr,"Error: unable to create new XPath context\n");
    return(NULL);
  }

  /* Evaluate xpath expression */
  xpathObj = xmlXPathEvalExpression((xmlChar *)xpath, xpathCtx);
  xmlXPathFreeContext(xpathCtx);
  if(xpathObj == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr,"Error: unable to evaluate xpath expression \"%s\"\n", xpath);
    return(NULL);
  }

  /* Check if xmlXPathEvalExpression had returned nonempty nodeset*/
  if (xmlXPathNodeSetIsEmpty(xpathObj->nodesetval)) {
    fprintf(stderr,"Error: empty set as a result of evaluation xpath expression \"%s\"",xpath);
    xmlXPathFreeObject (xpathObj);
    return(NULL);
  }

  nodeset = xpathObj->nodesetval;

  //there should be only one node in nodeset. So we return contents of the first node in nodeset
  return (char *)xmlNodeListGetString(xml_doc, nodeset->nodeTab[0]->xmlChildrenNode,1);
}

void fill_entry_from_rss(weatherSource *wsrc, xmlDocPtr filename, int doc_index) {
  /* Fill respective elements */
  wsrc->bolge = grabNodeFromFile(filename, "Bolge", doc_index);
  wsrc->peryot = grabNodeFromFile(filename, "Peryot", doc_index);
  wsrc->ili = grabNodeFromFile(filename, "ili", doc_index);
  wsrc->durum = grabNodeFromFile(filename, "Durum", doc_index);
  wsrc->mak = grabNodeFromFile(filename, "Mak", doc_index);
}

int fill_entry_from_rss_loop() {
  //int doc_item_index = 1;
  /* Load XML documents */
  doc = xmlParseFile("sonSOA.xml");
  if (doc == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: unable to parse file \"sonSOA.xml\"\n");
    return(0);
  }
  /* Allocate memory for weather struct */
  int num = 6;
  while (num > 0) {
    wsrc[(num - 1)] = g_new0(weatherSource, 1);
    num--;
  }
  /* Fill rss entries from their respective fields */
  fill_entry_from_rss(wsrc[0], doc, 1);
  printf("%s\n", wsrc[0]->ili);
  xmlFreeDoc(doc);
  return 1;
}
int main() {
  fill_entry_from_rss_loop();
  return 0;
}
```